# Difference between 偏見，偏私，and 偏心？

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin

偏見，偏私，and 偏心 all seem to mean `biased` in some form or another.

Is there a difference among the three, or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

偏见 is *bias of opinion or concept on different groups*, like race groups or religion groups.

偏心 is *bias of love on different persons*, like children.

偏私 is more used in ancient Chinese and it means *bias on people or group to which the subject belongs*.

Answer (score 1):

偏见 bias, prejudice

偏私 not impartial (especially when someone is supposed to be impartial)

偏心 (often referring to parents) love one of their children more than others.